# I can't install lutris as wine is not working

Tags: wine

So.... I was trying to  download Lutris on my linux mint 19.1, everything was going good until I was at the last step, which was installing wine by using this command:
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable

But I got this output:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Any help would be appreciated